# Asp.net's AutoEventWireup and reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, autoeventwireup

`AutoEventWireup` uses *reflection* searching page methods by `page_eventName`

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx)

> When AutoEventWireup is true, handlers are automatically bound to
>   events at run time based on their name and signature. For each event,
>   ASP.NET searches for a method that is named according to the pattern
>   Page_eventname, such as Page_Load or Page_Init.

Question :

Does he do it for *every* request ?

I looked in the `temporary internet files` (at `Microsoft.net` folder...) to see if he saves another file which contains explicit handler attachment - and *couldn't* find any .

Comment: Interesting question; it would not be *required* to do this per page, because the strategy can be cached (or even compiled via meta-programming). However, I do not know what it *actually* does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that ASP.NET uses cache for that as @Marc said. See internal `TemplateControl.HookUpAutomaticHandlers`.

A part of this method by using [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/):

```
internal void HookUpAutomaticHandlers()
{
  ...
  object obj = TemplateControl._eventListCache[(object) this.GetType()];
  if (obj == null)
  {
    lock (TemplateControl._lockObject)
    {
      obj = TemplateControl._eventListCache[(object) this.GetType()];
      if (obj == null)
      {
        IDictionary local_1_1 = (IDictionary) new ListDictionary();
        this.GetDelegateInformation(local_1_1);
        obj = local_1_1.Count != 0 ? (object) local_1_1 : TemplateControl._emptyEventSingleton;
        TemplateControl._eventListCache[(object) this.GetType()] = obj;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

Private `GetDelegateInformation` method is responsible for creating delegates for the control.
`TemplateControl._eventListCache` is a `Hashtable` which holds delegates per template control.

So, answering your question:

> Does he do it for every request ?

The answer is no. ASP.NET does it once to populate this `Hashtable`, and then uses cached values.

Comment: you mean static field `private static Hashtable _eventListCache;
 
` ...not cache....:-)